# angular full calendar change event background color when click

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

need to change the background color of event when click on the event in angular fullcalendar.
I have tried as setting event backgroundColor property within the click event but that was not update in view.

```
eventClick(e) {
     this.events.forEach(function (event) {
        if(event.id == e.calEvent.id) {
          event.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        }
      });

}
```

Comment: `this.events` does not belong to fullCalendar, presumably it's your own list of data. Simply updating an external list does not cause anything to be re-rendered on the calendar. Instead, use fullCalendar's methods (as per the documentation) to update events.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by adding event id(unique field which I used) as class for each events using 'className' property. then in event click event add following code to add class 'active-event' to clicked event in calendar.

```
onEventClick(e) {
    $('a.fc-timeline-event.fc-h-event.fc-event').removeClass('active-event'); 
    $('a.fc-timeline-event.fc-h-event.fc-event.'+ e.calEvent.id).addClass('active-event');      
  }
```

in css add following code

```
a.fc-timeline-event.fc-h-event.fc-event.active-event {
    background-color: 'red';
}
```

'a.fc-timeline-event.fc-h-event.fc-event' is classes which applied to all events in calendar.